# PanResponder React native parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with panResponder
My code :

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > 5,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove,
    });
  }

_handlePanResponderMove(event, gestureState) {
    if (gestureState.dy > current) {
      console.log("Down");
    } else {
      console.log("Up");
    }
    current = gestureState.dy;
  }

componentTag() {
   return tabTag.map((item, id) => {
      return(
        <View key={id} >
            <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
                <Icon name="ios-reorder" ></Icon>
            </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
}

render() {
   return (
     {this.componentTag}
   );
}
```

I would like to know when i am in the function _handlePanResponderMove the value of id of my array but i can't give parameters to the function

Comment: show us your whole component including constructor, and everything, this is too little information.

Comment: I don't have constructor my PanResponder.create is in componentWillMount

Answer (score 1):

The event parameter in handlePanResponderMove
Give you node id of the target of the touch.
I.e
Event.nativeEvent.target can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `componentTag` you're using `this` keyword, to do that, you'll need to bind `this` to your method.

You need a constructor like following:

```
constructor() {
   this.componentTag = this.componentTag.bind(this);

   //since you're using this keyword on componentDidMount as well,
   this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I won't say it'll fix everything, but it will fix some of your `undefined` errors

Comment: sorry but i think you have not understand what i want. I would like to know the id of my array in the function _handlePanResponderMove but tanks for read :)

Comment: Are you sure the component is being rendered on UI? can you see stuff on your screen? looks like there's some other error, anyway, here's the thing, you're using id in a key, and you can't access what key you are currently on. you need to pass to some other prop. How I'd do is to create a handler which sets the current state and access via that state.

Comment: yes i am sur the component is being rendered on UI. I don't understand i can't create  state and use it because if a use setState my page is rendered.

Comment: well, then try to add a onTap or something handler which sets a state, because key isn't accessible and you're using id only to give to key, key is an internal thing which react manages. I have tried to get key before, didn't work out.